# Minimum Android version with flutter

Tags: flutter, android-version

Which minimum android version is supported by flutter?
Do some plugins have any effect on which version is not supported?

I tried to run my flutter app on an android emulator, but with the version android 16 it doesn't work and the app crashes. Do I have to change the compile version in some config files or why doesn't it work?

Comment: If I remember correctly, you need a version >= 23

Comment: Are there compatibility issues with 2019 MacBook air and iPhone 5?

Comment: This link can be useful : https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Flutter support 16. But to run app on Android emulator, use over 19.

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11094
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9108
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/8610

Comment: To run on Android emulator 16-18, enable software rendering with `flutter run --enable-software-rendering` or in code https://stackoverflow.com/a/54064670/3522053

Answer (score 26):

From Flutters FAQ

[flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on](http://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on)

> Mobile operating systems: Android Jelly Bean, v16, 4.1.x or newer, and
> iOS 8 or newer.
>
> Mobile hardware: iOS devices (iPhone 4S or newer) and ARM Android
> devices.
>
> Note Flutter currently does not support building for x86 Android
> (issue [#9253](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9253)) directly, however apps built for ARMv7 or ARM64 run fine
> (via ARM emulation) on many x86 Android devices.
>
> We support developing Flutter apps with Android and iOS devices, as
> well as with Android emulators and the iOS simulator.
>
> We test on a variety of low-end to high-end phones but we don’t yet
> have an official device compatibility guarantee.
>
> We believe Flutter works well on tablets. We do not currently
> implement all of the tablet-specific adaptations recommended by
> Material Design, though we are planning further investment in this
> area

Answer (score 6):

The answer to this question also, partly, needs to take into consideration what parts of Android you want to take advantage of in your application. The question of what min version Flutter supports has been answered here a couple of times so I won't answer that, but the Android support libraries will also need specific min versions.

If you plan to use plugins of any kind then you will probably hit multiple issues if your min version is too low. Do you need Firebase? Do you need specific camera functions?

Google also just [announced](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html) required bumps for min versions with regards to Google Play that you should review.

My advice is to follow documentation, analytics and best practices to determine what you "true" min version should be.

Comment: Yes i use firebase. Which minimum version does firebase need?

Comment: I think you're somewhat missing the point in that it's up to you to understand all these things. You need to check each dependency or component and decide yourself based on limitations, optimizations, etc.

For what it is worth you can find the information on Google Play Services (Firebase requirement) here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup.

Comment: Follow-up question: What is it about Flutter that will cause minimum version issues to arise due to plugin dependencies? Or is this an issue I'll have with any Android app, Flutter aside?

Comment: Note the difference between "Target API" and "Min API". Google Play keeps upping the Target API but not necessarily the Min API.

Answer (score 2):

The Flutter documentation has this answer to Android and iOS. Now it says that support: Android Jelly Bean, v16, 4.1.x or newer, and iOS 8 or newer. However, this information can change according to the new Flutter version. By this reason, it is better that you review the next link:

```
     https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on
```

Furthermore, it would be best if you analyzed the plugins because they could need higher versions of Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

This answer can be useful :

**Devices and OS versions on which Flutter runs**

***Mobile operating systems:*** *Android Jelly Bean, v16, 4.1.x or newer, and iOS 8 or newer.*

***Mobile hardware:*** iOS devices (*iPhone 4S or newer*) and ARM Android devices.

> You can learn more [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/resources/faq#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on)