# Flutter build apk with --enable-software-rendering?

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
flutter build apk --enable-software-rendering
```

I need a release version that performs the say way as:

```
flutter run --enable-software-rendering --profile
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you need that for? I assume you have tried it and know whether it worked or not.

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/12010#issuecomment-385785392

Comment: Here's my issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17093

Comment: If flutter tries to use the hardware acceleration available on the Raspberry Pi, it becomes unusable. Almost as if the only time the screen refreshes is on user input, and even then, it's bad.

I can only get a usable app during profiling with --enable-software-rendering, so I'd like to be able to have a release apk with software rendering forced.

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR** Put `getIntent().putExtra("enable-software-rendering", true);` on top of your `onCreate()`

---

> Note - I assumed Android from the "apk" in question title and the need for software rendering.

Looking at the source code, the `--enable-software-rendering` flag for `flutter run` causes the activity to be launched using `am start` with `--ez enable-software-rendering true`, which puts that as a boolean extra into the intent.

If you wish to control when to use software rendering from code (such as depending on API level or device model), set the mentioned intent extra early in your `onCreate()`.

**Full Example:**

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;

public class MyActivity extends FlutterActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // use software rendering (ideally only when you need to)
        getIntent().putExtra("enable-software-rendering", true);

        // start Flutter
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: `import io.flutter.facade.Flutter;` is depreciated now. Any way around this?

Comment: @MichaelTolsma That call should not be needed with Flutter 1.12+, I have updated the example/imports.

Answer (score 1):

For those whom got here because are struggling with your Flutter Android app crashing with the following error

```
ERROR:flutter/shell/gpu/gpu_surface_gl Failed to setup Skia Gr context
```

when coming back to foreground after being put in background, just add *enable-software-rendering* to "onCreate" method as our friend **Matej Snoha** said above.

In other words, change `android/app/src/main/kotlin/[project]/MainActivity` file to the following Kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

    // add onCreate method (if not exists)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        // add this line to "onCreate" method
        this.getIntent().putExtra("enable-software-rendering", true)
        // don't forget to call "super"
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

}
```

It worked like a charm for me (no need to call `Flutter.startInitialization(this);` ).

Comment: `'onCreate' overrides nothing` is the error I receive

Answer (score 1):

Matej's answer provides the solution for Java based Flutter apps. For newly created apps using Kotlin for startup, the code looks like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        // use software rendering (ideally only when you need to)
        getIntent().putExtra("enable-software-rendering", true)

        // start Flutter
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

The `MainActivity` class is found in this path:

```
android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/.../.../MainActivity.kt
```