# flutter run returns error failed to create jar file

Tags: android, flutter, dart, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to run 'flutter run' but it returns the following error. Any idea on whats causing this to happen?

Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone x86. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\jars-8\54252edd90659a19228cc919a3e977c6\kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         6.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please refer this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50127070/flutter-build-apk-with-enable-software-rendering

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is, this folder
C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\jars-8\54252edd90659a19228cc919a3e977c6
Is currently empty. It should have kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar. How I fixed this problem, I have searched on Google for kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar. From Google, I have downloaded this kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar. After downloading I have pasted that particular jar file here -> C:\Users\User.gradle\caches\jars-8\54252edd90659a19228cc919a3e977c6.
Now I am not getting this error anymore.

You can download kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.3.50.jar from here :
https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-compiler-client-embeddable/1.3.50/source-code

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I freshly installed Flutter to my machine. I have created a new project, tried the compile it. In this first compilation process, it was taking long, so I have killed the compilation process with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> so that I can pass `--verbose` flag to `flutter run` to see what's taking so long. Then I got this error on the next verbose compilation.

Looking at the logs, I've managed to figure out that "Maybe, I have terminated the first compilation process while it was installing Gradle to my local machine, so it kinda screwed it up while it was doing its job.".

I have removed my `~/.gradle` directory and rerun again and it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I have been in the same error my problem was in

> kotlin version

I have update to new version and solved