# Flutter for Older Android Version

Tags: android, flutter

I am a newbie to Flutter ( ~ 2 weeks ) and I want to know the answers for the below basic questions.

#### 1. What is the minimum Android version Flutter supports ?

#### 2. How can we build the app for the older Android version ?

#### 3. Do we need to adjust our code if we target for older Android versions ( ex: Kitkat ) or the same code will work for any android version ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48802841/115145

Comment: 1. The referenced SO article only addresses the first question! 2.: You cannot build the app to a lower API level than the min SDK / API, however basically you target any devices at once which are between the minimum and the target API levels. 3. For any of those API levels you don't have to do anything, the Android compatibility libraries and the app distribution system should take care of the compatibility concerns. Unless you are doing some very special thing.

Answer (score 0):

this [Link](https://flutter.io/faq/#what-devices-and-os-versions-does-flutter-run-on) from Flutter official website explains the minimum SDK part of your question. As for older android phones you just have to enable software rendering using this command `flutter run --enable-software-rendering`.