# Which versions of android/ios will my flutter app run on?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I am building a flutter application that is about 70 percent complete and am wondering, how can I tell/set which android/ios versions it will run on?  How do you work with this with flutter?  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48802841/5557479

Answer (score 0):

you can configure your minimum targets for Android and iOS as you would in a native app, depending on your needs for each platform:

- Android: edit `android/app/build.gradle`, change `android.defaultConfig.minSdkVersion`.
- iOS: Xcode > select your project in the file tree > change the `Deployment Target`.